# What's the diffenence between self->_xxx and _xxx?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

There is some code:

```
@interface Person() {
    NSString *_name1;
}
@property NSString *name2;
@property void (^blk)(void);
@end
```

so, What's the diffenence between `self->_name1` and `_name1` ? And the difference between `self->_name2` and `_name2` ?

```
    __weak __typeof__(self) weakSelf = self;
    self.blk = ^(){
    __strong __typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
        _name1 = @"123";
    }
```

There will be retain cycle. The solution is that change `_name1` to `strongSelf->_name1`, But why ?

Comment: I don't think changing `_name1` to `self->_name1` make it work different. As I know, they are same.

Comment: My fault. I should use weakSelf.

Answer (score 2):

If `_name1` is an instance variable of a class `C` then in the body of an instance method of class `C` the simple variable reference:

```
_name1
```

is just a *shorthand* for:

```
self->_name1
```

and this means:

> access the instance variable `_name1` in the object referenced by variable `self`, and `self` is automatically set to reference the object on which the instance method was called (e.g. in `[v method ...]` when `method` is executed its `self` variable references the same object that the callers `v` referenced).

This shorthand means that accidental (not all retain cycles are unwanted or bad) retain cycles occur as uses of `self` are not immediately obvious.

In your code sample you have such a hidden reference to `self`, your use of `weakSelf` and `strongSelf` does *not* change the expansion of the shorthand, so:

```
_name1 = @"123";
```

still expands to:

```
self->_name1 = @"123";
```

And all your effort to avoid the retain cycle are wasted. To fix this you must not use the shorthand and instead write out what you do want:

```
strongSelf->_name1 = @"123";
```